# tkinter: my scrollbar hides some characters

Tags: tkinter, scrollbar

I have a the main window in my program as a Text widget, with a vertical scrollbar on the right side, along all its height - with the usual code:

```
yscrollbar=Scrollbar(mytext, orient=VERTICAL, command=mytext.yview)
mytext["yscrollcommand"]=yscrollbar.set
```

It is just annoying that when I insert/input text, the last 1-2 characters before the line returns are hidden by the scrollbar.

There is some easy way to tell the text widget to return the line before hitting the scrollbar?

PS the main window is user resizable, so I'm looking for some general solution...

Comment: Can you show a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? I tried making a minimal tkinter screen with just a Text widget and a scrollbar, didn't have the problem you describe.

Comment: It sounds like you are putting the scrollbar _in_ the window rather than beside it. Can you show how you create the scrollbar, and the pack or grid command you are using to make it visible?

Comment: @BryanOakley you're exactly right - sorry, it seems now obvious: it should have been mytext=Text(root,...) and Scrollbar(root,...). Thank you both!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your response to a question, the problem is that you are placing the scrollbar *inside* the text widget rather than *alongside* it. The solution is to give both the text widget and the scrollbar the same parent.

If you want the visual effect of the scrollbar being in the text widget, create a frame and give it a borderwidth of 1 and a relief of "sunken". Then, give your text widget a borderwidth of zero. Place both the text widget and the scrollbar in this frame and the scrollbar will have the appearance of being inside the text widget.